# Can "where" ever be used as the subject of a relative/adjective clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, dependent-clause

Here's the sentence that was confusing:

He went back to Santa Monica which was his hometown.

Why can't "which" be replaced with "where"?

"Where" can be used as a relative pronoun, but it's doesn't work here, despite Santa Monica being the noun described by the relative/adjective  clause. Why is this?

My theory is that this is because "where" cannot be the subject of the relative clause, that it can only the object, as in the case of:

He went back to Santa Monica where he was born.

Comment: Within the relative clause, "where" functions as **adjunct of place**, i.e. in/at some place. In your Santa Monica example, the relative clause is "he was born in Santa Monica. The "in" component is contributed by "where" together with its spacial location function.

Answer (score 5):

Given the examples

1. *He went back to Santa Monica, which was his hometown.*
   (The comma is necessary for a non-restrictive relative clause)
2. **He went back to Santa Monica, where was his hometown.*
   (ungrammatical because of *where*)
3. *He went back to Santa Monica, where he was born.*
   (grammatical despite *where*),

your theory is partly correct.

Yes, the locative relative pronoun *where* can't be the subject of a relative clause, **unless**  there's also a locative predicate in the relative clause; a location **can** be the subject of a locative predicate:

- *Santa Monica, where stands the famous Bridge Over Troubled Waters*

But not normally.
However, in (3), *where* is **not** the object of *be born*, which is intransitive and can't have an object.
Even if the clause is transitive, its object is unlikely to be a locative:

- *Santa Monica, where I spent Hanukkah*

*Where, when, why,* and *how* are adjectival or adverbial in nature, and don't normally function as noun phrases, which is the minimum necessary for a subject, direct object, or indirect object. The relative clauses these *wh*-words introduce tend to modify words that refer to the same kind of adverbial:

- *the reason why `S` ~ the time when `S` ~ the place where `S`* (but **not** **the way how `S`*
  --  *how* can only be used without antecedent or *wh*-word ~ *how to do it **or** the way she did it*)

Comment: But where isn't the clear-cut subject of *where stands the famous BOTW* or certainly no more than *there* is in *There stands the famous BOTW* - they both can be analysed as having post-posed subjects, can't they?

Comment: The locative _there_  is stressed, while the dummy _there_ is unstressed (the verb _stands_ is stressed). As usual, there's only a problem in the written version.

Comment: I think what I was angling at was: is the word *where* actually the subject of *where stands the famous Bridge Over Troubled Waters*? Or is it the case, maybe, that *the famous Bridge Over Troubled Waters* is the subject, but that it's been shunted down to the end of the clause (aka been postposed)? I think that's what I was reaching for, but it was a long time ago!

Comment: ... and you're not here any more. Where are you, btw?

Comment: Ah, I'm not doing answer posts on EL&U. Was originally  for other reasons, but now primarily to ensure I get enough work done on my PhD thesis! Am currently in the wet and grim reaches of North East England.

Comment: Lemme know if there's any help I can give you.