# "The place where is near my apartment" - Why can't we use 'where' there?

Tags: that, where-which

This question here asks about *where* as a subject in relative clauses:

- [Can "where" ever be used as the subject of a relative/adjective clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311612/can-where-ever-be-used-as-the-subject-of-a-relative-adjective-clause)

As can be seen from my specific questions at the end (as opposed to the back-story), the specific question here is more fundamental and more general.

---

I have a Taiwanese friend who asks me for English help with some regularity. I believe I am almost always able to furnish them with the correct answer, but the latest topic is one of which I'm unable to explain the 'why'.

The sentence in question:

> The office will be moved to a place which/where is near my apartment.

I said it should be

> The office will be moved to a place which is  near my apartment.

(or: *a place **that** is near my apartment* ).

My friend asked '"Why? Doesn't *where* indicate a place?"

Erm, ... yes, but no... I can't explain the why of it, and now I'm really curious. When should we use *where* and when *which* or *that*? Any input will be much appreciated!

Comment: Related: [Relative pronouns “where” and “when”: where can they be omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432219) "Place" is a special kind of noun.

Comment: @Araucaria I have flagged, requesting for the duplicate to be merged with this, in the light of your full answer.