# Using which or where to refer to place

Tags: relative-pronouns

A student I have been volunteering with wrote the following in his essay:

> We really enjoyed the cruise and also the islands where we visited last week.

To  my ear the use of *where* doesn't sound right. I would use *which*.

However, after searching various resources I found a couple of websites which stated that we use *where* when it is followed by a subject/ verb pair and *which* is used when it is the subject.

This doesn't seem to work here.

Can someone please tell me why.  Thanks

Comment: Neither "where"  nor "which" is needed. "We really enjoyed the cruise and the islands we visited last week" is fine.

Comment: See  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/311612.

Comment: I agree with @J. Taylor and see no reason for the prepositional madness (at, which, where and to) below...

Answer (score 3):

You can use either one. You can also use *that*. Finally, as J. Taylor pointed out in the comments, you may also choose to use no word in that position.

The most controversial to you seems to be the version with *where*. Here are examples of such constructions from published literature:

*It reminded her of the pansies that bloomed in her aunt's garden, **where** she visited last summer.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=vGI3AQAAMAAJ&dq=%22where%20she%20visited%20last%22&pg=RA2-PA434#v=onepage&q=%22where%20she%20visited%20last%22&f=false)
*Today, she will bring us up to date on the current situation of China, **where** she visited last year.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ek0iAAAAMAAJ&q=%22where+she+visited+last%22&dq=%22where+she+visited+last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDkf6L1_jfAhXARRUIHQmyClcQ6AEINDAC)
*Boulette's Larder feels like someone's home, or perhaps a kitchen in Italy, **where** we visited last fall.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=CJUvAQAAMAAJ&q=%22where+we+visited+last%22&dq=%22where+we+visited+last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi52PSK2PjfAhW3UhUIHbDKD3sQ6AEILjAB)
*Mr. and Mrs. Harry Howard, Mr. and Mrs. Harry Poett, and Miss Emily Carolan have returned from Santa Barbara, **where** they visited last week with Miss Sarah Redington.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UaxPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA335&dq=%22where+they+visited+last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4xduw2PjfAhWwXhUIHd_BDZ0Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22where%20they%20visited%20last%22&f=false)
*Instead of going downwards back to the cave **where** they visited last night they went upward.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=A1I8SYwdxIEC&lpg=PA204&dq=%22Instead%20of%20going%20downwards%20back%20to%20the%20cave%20where%20they%20visited%20last%20night%20they%20went%20upward%22&pg=PA204#v=onepage&q=%22Instead%20of%20going%20downwards%20back%20to%20the%20cave%20where%20they%20visited%20last%20night%20they%20went%20upward%22&f=false)
*I have… submitted to the Public Housing Administration a development program for the McKees Rocks area adjoining the area **where** you visited yesterday.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZcIuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22where+you+visited+yesterday%22&dq=%22where+you+visited+yesterday%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD1K_75PjfAhWq5OAKHd3lD_gQ6AEIKjAA)

In the last two, the *where* clause is integrated into the structure of the sentence, whereas in the others it is a supplement, as indicated by the comma that precedes it.

**Discussion**

The choice of *which,* *that*, or no word vs *where* depends on whether *visit* is taken as a transitive or an intransitive verb. Note that *visit* has both transitive and intransitive senses, see e.g. [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visit), [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/visit), … In its intransitive sense, *visit* means *to make a visit*.

**Analysis of the various options**

We have four options. All four are **relative constructions.** Two are *wh*-relatives (with *which* and *where*), and two are non-*wh* relatives, one with the subordinator *that*, and one with a bare relative.

In the version with *where*, the verb *visit* is taken as intransitive. In the other three versions, it is taken as transitive.

**1. *which***

[1] *We enjoyed the islands [which we visited last week].*

This is a **relative construction,** and the part in the brackets is a **relative clause.** Simplifying matters somewhat, the pronoun *which* serves as the object of the verb *visited*, except that it has been **fronted** i.e. moved from its usual position after the verb to the front, to a 'prenuclear position' (i.e. the position 'before the subject + predicate construction that constitutes the nucleus of the clause' ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 1037). The antecedent of *which* is the nominal *islands* (without the article). In particular, one might say that 'embedded into' [1] is the following clause: *We visited (some) islands last week,* where *(some) islands* is the object of *visited.*

CGEL indicates these facts as follows:

*We enjoyed the **islands**<sub>i</sub> [**which**<sub>i</sub> we visited ____<sub>i</sub> last week.]*

The '*____<sub>i</sub>*' is called a **gap**, and there are technical reasons why we consider this gap as what really serves as the object of *visited*. The relative word *which* is, on the one hand, linked to the gap, and on the other hand, it has *islands* as its antecedent. We use the subscript index *i* to indicate these relationships. According to CGEL (p. 1038), 'prenuclear elements that are linked to a gap are interpreted as having the function of that gap, and we can thus say in a secondary, derivative, sense that they have that function.'

**2. *where***

[2] *We enjoyed the islands [where we visited last week].*

The grammar of [2] is completely analogous to the grammar of

[2a] *We enjoyed the islands [where we slept last week].*

The structure of [2] is indicated as follows:

*We enjoyed the **islands**<sub>i</sub> [**where**<sub>i</sub> we visited last week].*

Note that this time there is no gap, because *visited* is taken as an intransitive verb, just like *slept*.

According to CGEL (p. 1050), '*where* takes locative expressions as antecedent; within the relative clause it functions as adjunct of spatial location, goal complement, or complement of a locative preposition.' Further, CGEL provides an analysis of the sentence

[3] *She wanted to see the house [where she had grown up].*

CGEL says:

> A 'double-variable' representation of [3] is "She wanted to see house *x*; she had grown up in *x*": the "in" component is contributed by *where* together with its spatial location function, with the antecedent determining the value of the variable *x*.

The corresponding double-variable representation of [2] is "We enjoyed islands *x*; we visited on *x* last week."

The correct preposition that is contributed by *where* is *on*. Here are related examples of such usage from published literature:

*He had visited **on** the Island of Elba that was Napoleon's home during his exile.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=vgoUGbeIgF4C&lpg=PA75&dq=%22visited%20on%20the%20island%22&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=%22visited%20on%20the%20island%22&f=false) 
*…Creeley' s relationships with painters some of whom visited **on** the island…* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ga6KmklziEAC&lpg=PA439&dq=%22visited%20on%20the%20island%22&pg=PA439#v=onepage&q=%22visited%20on%20the%20island%22&f=false)

**3. *that***

[4] *We enjoyed the islands [that we visited last week].*

Here the structure is

*We enjoyed the **islands**<sub>i</sub> [that we visited ____<sub>i</sub> last week.]*

Note that *visited* is here taken in its transitive meaning, and the function of the object is again performed by the gap. So this case is quite similar to the *which* case discussed above. One difference, according to CGEL, *that* is not a pronoun here, but a subordinator (pp. 1056-1057), which is why it doesn't get a subscript index *i*. This case is closely related to...

**4. bare relative**

[5] *We enjoyed the islands [we visited last week].*

This is obtained from [4] by omitting the subordinator *that*. The structure is

*We enjoyed the **islands**<sub>i</sub> [we visited ____<sub>i</sub> last week.]*

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. I stopped actively reading after that—but what I glanced at looked good. ;)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. much appreciated.

Comment: @user242899 No problem!

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks! There is one place where I'm not completely sure, and that's whether the construction *He had visited **on** the Island of Elba* is acceptable. I'm quite sure that if *any* preposition works there, it has to be *on*, but I'm not 100% sure *on* works, either (and if it doesn't, then one simply cannot add an adjunct of location to a clause that uses *visit* in its intransitive meaning). Indeed, the two examples I quote there are the *only* two I could find.

Comment: *Visiting* can be used intransitively. An example used by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visit) is *enjoys visiting with the neighbours*. But if that's syntactically correct, then so is simply *enjoys visiting* as well as *he visited*. And if that's correct, then so is *he had visited* and *he had visited on the island.* If you can *visit with* you can surely also *visit on*.  And you could also *visit while*, *visit during*,  and others. But while technically correct, I expect it would almost never be used. (Aside from in the few instances you found.)

Comment: In that specific sentence, it does seems as if **on** is the only preposition that makes common sense. But you could, for instance, use **under** if he went there in a submarine or **over** if he went there in a hot-air balloon . . .